# React/React Hooks: I am trying to trigger a validation using hooks whenever a user leaves input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that I’ve designed using react hooks with on change functionality wired up so that the input field is pre-populated with a customer email address, and if the user clicks the email opt out checkbox it clears and disables the input. I am now trying to design an on change event when a user enters a new email address and leaves the input field that will trigger an email validation to ensure it’s the correct format. I have written a function using regex that contains the error message I want to display, but I’m not sure how to implement it with my main component as it stands now. I've included the validation function as well as my main component below. I’m fairly new to hooks so trying to wrap my head around how to implement all of this logic has proven to be a bit difficult, so any suggestions/code examples on how to pull this off would be a huge help

```
Function for Email Validation
```

```
export default function validate(values) {
  let errors = {};
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is required';
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is invalid';
  }
  return errors;
};
```

```
Main Component
```

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  Col, Row, Icon, Input, Tooltip
} from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import Markup from '../core/Markup'

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {}, account = {}, site = {} } = customer || {}
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false)
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email)

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(' ')
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput()
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue)
  }


  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>{account.name}</h2>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Primary Contact:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{contact.name}</P>
          <P>{contact.phone}</P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Service Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <P>{site.address1}</P>
          <P>{site.address2}</P>
          <P>
            {site.city},&nbsp;{site.state}&nbsp;
            {site.postalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <H3>
            <strong>Billing Address:</strong>
          </H3>
          <StyledMarkup>{account.billingStreet}</StyledMarkup>
          <P>
            {account.billingCity},&nbsp;{account.billingState}
            &nbsp;
            {account.billingPostalCode}
          </P>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Col span={10}>
          <h4>
            PRIMARY CONTACT EMAIL &nbsp;
            <Tooltip
              placement="right"
              title={primaryContact}
            >
              <StyledTooltipIcon
                type="question-circle"
                theme="filled"
              />
            </Tooltip>
          </h4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} />
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledCheckbox
            value={disableInput}
            onChange={CheckboxClick}
          /> EMAIL
          OPT OUT{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
    </Container>
  )
}

CustomerDetails.propTypes = {
  customer: PropTypes.object
}

CustomerDetails.defaultProps = {
  customer: {}
}

export default CustomerDetails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it:

See if that works for you.

```js
function validateEmail(value) {
  let errors = {};
  if (value === '') {
    errors.email = 'Email address is required';
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is invalid';
  }
  return errors;
};

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
  
  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }
  
  function onBlur(e) {
    setErrors(validateEmail(e.target.value));
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div>Fill the email input and click elsewhere to blur the field</div>
      <input onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} value={inputValue} placeholder="Enter email..."/>
      {errors.email && <div>{errors.email}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I have modified your validation function to make it simpler for my example. But you can adjust that to your needs.

Comment: This is working, but now my disable function doesn't grey out the input and it still flashes an error message for an invalid email underneath. Any ideas on how to get around this so that the input still greys out and doesn't display an error message when it's disabled?

Comment: If you can, go to http://codesandbox.io , create a React Sandbox, add the dependencies you need and try to build an example of the problem with minimal functionality.

Comment: Yeup just created one here: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-breeze-2ly5h. For some reason the positioning is off so I'm working to correct that but all of the current behavior is the same

Comment: Hey yeup! This is working now, but now I have a problem where I need the validation to run and throw the error message if a user clicks the checkbox a second time. Any idea on how to do this? I essentially need to toggle the state between throwing the error if the input is active and the field is either empty or the email is the wrong format, and disabling the input/clearing the field when someone clicks the checkbox. If they click the checkbox a second time, the input field will once again be active and empty so I need the error message to appear again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onBlur` in your component and hook that up with props `this.props.blur` now if you import your component. You can simply use `blur`

```
<styledInput blur={()=> this.validationFunction()}/>
```

now behind the scenes react knows to cast the functionality of the onBlur event to the prop it was mapped to.